# Ubuntu 20.04 fingerprint device disconnect during enroll

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have a asus vivobook 14 laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.

fingerprint login (during setting up/ enrolling) detects my fingerprint device, but after attempting to scan, it disconnects the device.

[image]